# Как скопировать известный файл который лежит в одной из папок в %PATH%

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Команда вот такая примерно:

```
copy /b 7zS2.sfx + config.txt + boundle.7z dounble.exe
```

Файл `7zS2.sfx` находится в одной из папок в %PATH% и команда `copy` не выполняется так как этот файл найти не может. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@for /f "tokens=1* delims=*" %%i in ('@where 7zS2.sfx') do @if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" set "filepath=%%i"
if not exist "%filepath%" exit
copy /b "%filepath%" + config.txt + boundle.7z dounble.exe
```

Comment: При условии, что имеется только 1 файл, а то все найденные файлы в кучу сольются, да еще и по нескольку раз. Точнее говоря, только последний найденный будет успешно "слит" с необходимыми.

Comment: А если попробывать `i` в переменную сохранить?

Comment: Так сохраняйте куда хотите и используйте. Тогда получается, как минимум, две строки в батч-файле: **for /f %%i in ('@where 7zS2.sfx') do set "filepath=%%i"** и **copy /b "%filepath%" + config.txt + boundle.7z dounble.exe**. Между ними можно ещё и строку проверки существования файла влепить **if not exist "%filepath%" exit**

Comment: Если путь с пробелами то обрезает по первый пробел

Comment: Надо тогда полностью захватывать путь, например, заданием разделительного символа равным *. См.измененный ответ

Comment: tokens=1* это точно?

Comment: **'tokens=1*'** диктует передавать в переменную **%%i** все символы до разделителя, а оставшееся во вторую **%%j**. Можно было бы **'tokens=*'**. Но в данном случае и тот, и другой вариант сработает.